# Unknown provider: $httpProvider <- $http

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue with dependency inject in Angular. I've done a simple example to demonstrate the error I'm getting

```
function MyService($http) {
    this.doIt = function () {
       console.log("done");
    }
}

var myModule = angular.module("myModule", []);

myModule.service("myService", ['$http', MyService]);

var prx = angular.injector(['myModule']).get('myService');
prx.doIt();
```

The error I'm getting is "Unknown provider: $httpProvider <- $http <- myService"

So i'm assuming its something to do with the injection.

In my case i need to use the angular injector because i'm trying to integrate a new client library with an old application that isn't written with Angular.

Comment: where are you bootstrapping the angular module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can monkey-patch to use `myModule`'s service with `ng` module.

```
var prx = angular.injector(['myModule', 'ng']).get('myService');
```

here is [the worked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/899w2ynk/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out using the RTFM technique.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector

states here

> The ng module must be explicitly added.

So i need to do this

```
var prx = angular.injector(['ng','myModule']).get('myService');
```

To get it to work. I've updated the fiddle.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The line where you define your module you need to tell that this module requires $http. So this line should be replaced with the line below.

```
var myModule = angular.module("myModule", []);

var myModule = angular.module("myModule", ['$http']);
```

Comment: After trying this i am now getting Failed to instantiate module myModule due to: Failed to instantiate module $http due to: Module '$http' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I have created this code sample https://plnkr.co/edit/LHoZL9aJvurq4DUJmPwl?p=preview Please have a look at it. Why do you want to call the service outside a controller?

Comment: Yep, i can get it to work in the controller as well. I need it to work outside a controller though so i need to use the angular.injector afaik. As I said in the original post I have a new library written in Angular (from a 3rd party) that i need to use in an old app that isn't written using Angular.